# Prevent Raspberry Pi reboot from brief voltage interrupt using capacitors

Tags: capacitor, battery-charging, raspberry-pi, charging, voltage

My goal is to power a Raspberry Pi Zero W using an IP5306 charging IC which would receive its power input from a 3.7 V 18650 battery. The Raspberry Pi Zero requires 5 V and can draw as much as 120 mA without HDMI running.

The IP5306 should be able to power the Raspberry Pi from its battery source in theory. The issue I am running into is the following scenario:

The Raspberry Pi Zero W is currently on and is being powered by the IP5306 charging IC. The 18650 is running out of juice so it is now time to charge the battery using an external 5 V power supply. As soon as the external 5 V is applied to the IP5306 to charge the 18650, there is a VERY brief interrupt in the voltage output of the IP5306. This interrupt is brief enough where you wouldn't even see an LED flicker but it is long enough to cause a Raspberry Pi and even an MCU to reboot.

This brief voltage output interrupt is a trait of the IP5306 itself.

I would like to know what I can do to prevent the Raspberry Pi Zero W from losing power when the external 5 V is applied to the IP5306.

Would I need to add a Schottky diode with some ceramic capacitors in parallel between the IP5306 and the Pi? If so, how many capacitors and what would their values have to be.

I don't know the exact duration of the output interrupt in ms.

Comment: The question has been answered here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/171531/260528

Comment: See answer mentioned by George, but: C ~= time_off x current / Voltage-droop. || So for eg 100 mS, 125 mA and 1V acceptable drop : C = 0.1s x 0.125A / 1v = 0.0125 F = 12,500 uF.

Answer (score 1):

This has been addressed in a practical manner here: https://whiteboxcellphone.com/psd/rpi-supercap.html

Basically, a supercapacitor across pins 2 and 6 of the GPIO will charge while the Pi is powered and discharge for a few seconds when it is not. However, you have to balance the benefit of a large capacitor against the ability of the charger to feed the capacitor at boot.

Between 10F and 25F often works.

Comment: 10F capacitor? Can you please back up this value with a calculation?

Comment: Unless you know the duration and form of the power interruption and the impedance of the Pi, you have to use trial and error. 10F to 25F is based on experience with a Raspberry Pi 4, but depends on what accessories are attached and the actual input voltage. Please see the link.